# CSS Transition doesn't work with hamburger button

Tags: jquery, html, css, transition

I made a hamburger button and I'm trying to animate spans to create a cross.

My transition doesn't work and I don't know why... 
I found that sometimes transitions doesn't work on chrome so I've used webkit prefix but it didn't help :(

This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="main__box__nav__hamburger">
    <span class="line line1"></span>
    <span class="line line2"></span>
    <span class="line line3"></span>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.main__box__nav__hamburger {
  min-width: 30px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 45px 10px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.28, 1.54) .5s;
}
.line {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 30px;
  height: 4px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: #000;
}
.line2 {
  top: 8px;
}
.line3 {
  top: 16px;
}
.main__box__nav__hamburger.close .line1 {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 50%;
}
.main__box__nav__hamburger.close .line2, .main__box__nav__hamburger.close .line3 {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: 50%;
}
```

Comment: How do you initiate the animation?

Comment: [example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_menu_icon.asp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are applying the transition to the parent element (the hamburger itself), instead of to its children. Remember that `transition` is not inherited.

Move the `transition` property to the `.line` selector and it will work:

```
.line {
  transition: all cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.28, 1.54) .5s;
}
```

See proof-of-concept below (I have added some minimal JS, so clicking on the hamburger will toggle the `close` class needed to visualize the transition):

```js
var burger = document.querySelector('.main__box__nav__hamburger');

burger.addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.classList.toggle('close');
});
```

```css
.main__box__nav__hamburger {
  min-width: 30px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 45px 10px;
  position: relative;
}
.line {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 30px;
  height: 4px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: #000;
  transition: all cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.28, 1.54) .5s;
}
.line2 {
  top: 8px;
}
.line3 {
  top: 16px;
}
.main__box__nav__hamburger.close .line1 {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 50%;
}
.main__box__nav__hamburger.close .line2, .main__box__nav__hamburger.close .line3 {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main__box__nav__hamburger">
    <span class="line line1"></span>
    <span class="line line2"></span>
    <span class="line line3"></span>
</div>
```